# How to parse a SOAP response containing an XML Document inside the response tag

Tags: ios, soap, xml-parsing

I am sending a SOAP request to the server and getting the following response. I am parsing the response using the DDXMLParser. However, the parser interprets this as an invalid XML. I am pretty sure that the data inside the`<return>`  tag has to be wrapped in `[!CDATA]` blocks. When parsing using the `NSXML Parser` i am getting `NSXMLParser Error Domain 64`. 
I am unsure as how to proceed now.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soapenv:Body>
          <return>
          <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <catalog>
              <book id="bk101">
                <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
                <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
                <genre>Computer</genre>
                <price>44.95</price>
                <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
                <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
              </book>
              <book id="bk102">
                <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
                <title>Midnight Rain</title>
                <genre>Fantasy</genre>
                <price>5.95</price>
                <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
                <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
          an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
          of the world.</description>
              </book>
            </catalog>
          </return>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any document can have only one XML declaration and it must be at the very beginning of the document.

The parser will see this as either nesting of documents or improper placement of the XML declaration, both of which will cause an error.

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>**
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soapenv:Body>
          <return>
          **<?xml version="1.0"?>**
            <catalog>
```